# ERROR: Error installing bond:

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I added some gems to my Gemfile, specifically activerecord, sinatra-activerecord, sqlite3, shotgun, and tux. When I ran 'bundle install' I get this weird error that doesn't seem to have any Googleable information about it. Here is the error I get:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

make "DESTDIR=" clean


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make "DESTDIR="


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make failed, exit code 69

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bond-0.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/bond-0.5.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bond (0.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bond -v '0.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then run the suggested

```
gem install bond -v '0.5.1'
```

and get this:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bond:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb

make "DESTDIR=" clean


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make "DESTDIR="


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make failed, exit code 69

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bond-0.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/bond-0.5.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.